# SQL find which tables were updated.

Tags: sql, oracle

This may be a simple question, but I wasn't able to find an answer. A Few months ago I asked for help making a query that determines all the tables that were updated. I was able to get it working, but it is slow and it only writes to the DBMS Output window. I ultimately went another direction with my project. Now I have an EXCEL VBA workbook that pulls all the tables and queries each one for updates related to a given project.  This is just as slow but gives me more to work with. As it runs through the list of tables it queries those tables where the update count is greater than zero.

What I would really like is some way to get the list of tables with the update count all in one in much less time. For example, a query like the one below, would give me the two columns that I am currently building with my slow VBA script.

```
Select distinct atc.table_name 
    , (select distinct count(project_id)from atc.table_name where project_id like 'XXXXX')) as CNT
from all_tab_cols 
where column_name like 'PROJECT_ID'
```

This query gives me the error table/view does not exist. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Create a log table that you write to whenever you update a table then pull stats from that

Comment: Do you have the proper indexes created for your query predicate?

Comment: Thanks Daniel, but that isn't going to work. There are hundreds of updates being made everyday. I am not a DBA, just a guy in charge of making sure that some of those updates are made correctly.

Comment: Sorry to say it, but I'm afraid that *your* Excel  VBA way of doing it is a wrong way. You could/should enable audit. Or, as suggested, create log table(s), create database triggers which would *log* changes made on those tables. Involving Excel into it is, in my opinion, a suicidal task.

Comment: Littlefoot - I don't disagree, but I am in the middle of everything and only have read privileges. I did some digging based on what OldProgrammer said and see that we do log the changes that are moved to our production server, but I need to find the changes before that happens. There does not seem to be a log for that.

Comment: "Changes before they happen" can be trapped with a BEFORE ROW triggers, by comparing `:old` and `:new` column values. But, if you only have read privileges, you probably have to live with what you have, and that's your Excel VBA. Sorry, I can't help much with that but wish you luck!

Comment: Littlefoot - Let me explain a little more. The Log is created when changes are moved to our production server from the test server. My job is to quality control changes made on the test server. When the system was built, someone who doesn't do my job built a tool that exports changes associated with a project. Except, the tool doesn't give us all the information that we would want to see. I am just trying to do the best I can to bridge the gap. And, I have for the most part succeeded already. It is just much slower than I would like.